# MultipleObjectsReturned at /cart/ get() returned more than one Order -- it returned 3

Tags: django

I want to use get_or_create in my code, but when it returns more than one record, it shows MultipleObjectsReturned error. If there is single record its runs fine.

Code at Views.py

```
def cart(request):
       if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer=request.user.customer
        order , created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
       items=[]
       order={'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
    context={'items':items, 'order': order}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it means you have more than one record with customer=customer, complete=False, but get_or_create() require single match.

- Delete other records
- or add more fields to get_or_create
- or use create() instead of get_or_create() if you need multiple records

Comment: By using filter and create  I think will work fine but i was looking to reduce the line of codes.

Answer (score 0):

The [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) is assumed to behave so (i.e. perform `get` on the queryset and if it does not exist do a create. It only handles `DoesNotExist` but not `MultipleObjectsReturned`). Your use case maybe is to "ensure at least one object" instead of "ensure exactly one object". Then you have to code it yourself something like this:

```
queryset = Order.objects.filter(customer=customer, complete=False)
if queryset.exists():
    obj, created = queryset.first(), False
else:
    obj, created = Order.objects.create(customer=customer, complete=False), True
```

Comment: Why you add .first() and False, Can you please explain this line.

Comment: I added that to mimic the behavior of original `get_or_create`, unless to tolerate multiple objects. If I didn't get your problem correctly please let me know.